# Timeout when importing a grails project

Tags: java, grails, groovy, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to import a Grails project into STS. I'm running STS 3.6.1. I've also got the Groovy plugin installed, running compiler 1.8.6. Finally, I have Grails 2.1.4.

When I try to import a Grails project though (which is a Subversion repository), it is *painfully* slow, before it finally gives up:

> The command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe (4 Sep
>   2014 12:10:28)' was terminated because it didn't produce new output
>   for some time.
>
> See details for the output produced so far.
>
> If you think the command simply needed more time, you can increase the
>   time limit in the Grails preferences page.
>
> See menu Windows >> Preferences >> Grails >> Launch Command:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javaw.exe (4 Sep 2014 12:10:28)
>   ---- System.out ---- | Loading Grails 2.1.4 | Configuring classpath | Downloading:
>   C:\Users\607534885\Software\grails-2.1.4\plugins\database-migration-1.3.2.pom
>   | Downloading:
>   C:\Users\607534885\Software\grails-2.1.4\lib\org.liquibase\liquibase-core\ivy-2.0.5.xml
>   | Downloading:
>   C:\Users\607534885\Software\grails-2.1.4\plugins\jquery-1.8.3.pom
>   ---- System.err ----
>
> Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds
>   ------System.out:-----------  | Loading Grails 2.1.4 | Configuring classpath | Downloading:
>   C:\Users\607534885\Software\grails-2.1.4\plugins\database-migration-1.3.2.pom
>   | Downloading:
>   C:\Users\607534885\Software\grails-2.1.4\lib\org.liquibase\liquibase-core\ivy-2.0.5.xml
>   | Downloading:
>   C:\Users\607534885\Software\grails-2.1.4\plugins\jquery-1.8.3.pom
>   ------System.err:-----------
>
> Terminating process: Timeout: no new output for 180000 milliseconds

Why is Grails proving to be so slow? Or is this an issue with something else?

Comment: does it gives other errors in several attemts with the downloading of the files?  can't you run it once on command line to load all the deps first?

Comment: checkout the project using some external tool, like tortoise-svn, and then import it into GGTS

Comment: @injecteer. That's what I'm doing. It's checked out using Tortoise, then imported into STS (not using GGTS at recommendation of dev team)

Comment: @cfrick: Do you mean import project in Eclipse, then run it on cmd line? Why would that produce a different result?

Comment: no, i suspect, that downloading all the dependencies takes its time and eclipse just kills the process in the middle of it.  if you would just do a `grails package` in your project root and let it setup itself without disturbance i would assume, that eclipse will load it.

Comment: @cfrick: apologies for a simple question, but how do I do a grails package in my project?

Comment: @cfrick: Currently, I'm right clicking the project in STS, going to Grails tool and choosing to Refresh dependencies, which is not working

Comment: when you do this, will the error message change very attempt?  to me it looks like that grails is downloading dependencies.  as for running on command line: you either must have the `grailsw.bat` for windows in your project or must known, where your grails is installed.  then chdir into the project on your terminal and call it.  i can not produces the exact steps for windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Rather pointless question in the end. We have an aggressive firewall in work and I simply needed to use a wifi connection instead as importing the project for the first time required third party software to be installed. Simples in the end.